# Setting one of dependent (has_many) records as primary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I am building a simple RoR application. In the app I have `Person` model that has `has_many` association with `PhoneNumber` model.

Now I would like to implement following functionality. If a person has at least one phone numbers then one of his numbers should be set as primary number.

What are best practices in such case?

I am thinking about adding new boolean column `primary` to `PhoneNumber` model and setting it to `true` inside the model when first number is associated with person

Comment: i think you are going in right direction. when user add a phone number check for previous numbers if no previous numbers found set that one as primary no.